# Using substring of JSON key value for conditionals

Tags: jquery, json

I have some JSON data that will look something like this:

```
   {
  "events": [
    {
      "event": {
        "event_instances": [
          {
            "event_instance": {
              "id": 1365348,
              "ranking": 0,
              "event_id": 460956,
              "start": "2015-07-07T00:00:00-05:00",
              "end": null,
              "all_day": true
            }
          }
        ],
        "id": 460956,
        "title": "Blue Star Museums",
        "url": "http:\/\/www.samhoustonmemorialmuseum.com\/",
        "updated_at": "2015-07-07T05:27:49-05:00",
        "created_at": "2015-06-02T12:34:01-05:00",
        "facebook_id": null,
        "first_date": "2015-06-02",
        //so on and so forth
```

I'm need to use that `first_date` key value in a jQuery conditional that will basically say something like this:

```
if(first_date.value().substring(0,3) === 2015){
    //do something
}
```

Can you use substrings of key values for conditionals in jQuery?

Comment: try using var object = $.parseJSON(jsonString) and then you can use object.events and so on..

Comment: Notice that with `===` you may want to use strings on both sides (i.e.: `"2015" === 2015` returns `false`).

Comment: @Armfoot nice catch. Noted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So assuming that that json is assigned to some variable named `jsonVariable`

```
var first_date = jsonVariable.events[0].event.first_date;
var first_date_year = first_date.substring(0,4);

if (first_date_year === '2015') {
    // do somethang
}
```

### How to access `first_date`

First to access `first_date` you have to access the array `events`, the first element of that array (using the index `[0]`), then the `event` property, and finally its sub property `first_date`

### How to take the substring

To take the substring you need to use `substr(0,4)` because the second parameter is the `length` in characters of the substring not the `index` position to end it.

### How to compare years

Then to compare the substring with `2015` you need to wrap the 2015 in quotes to convert it to a string, or use `parseInt()` to convert the substring to an integer.

**Note:** You could also split the string at `-` and use the first element

```
var first_date = jsonVariable.events[0].event.first_date;
var first_date_year = first_date.split('-').pop(); // ["2015", "06", "02"] pop the first value
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
var year = MyJSON.events[0].event.first_date.substring(0,4);

if ( year === '2015' ) { ... }
```